# Importing a Maven project as a sub project in an existing project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to import a maven project into eclipse as a subproject of a non-maven project.
The structure am seeking should look like the image below

[image]

I have tried to import the parent project and then create spring starter project and select the path to be inside the parent but I ended up with an independent project in the workspace that is duplicated in parent.
Thank in advance.

Comment: This generally sounds like a bad idea. I doubt there is any support for that.

Comment: I agree, that might not be the way things usually are. but am following a tutorial that is done in IntelliJ and am wondering if different IDEs may have different capabilities.

Comment: Use a git submodule.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen am not sure what that is but am not just trying to structure the project on file, I was trying to structure it in workspace.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that. What you can do is a modular maven project. Declare your `spring-cloud` as parent and `guest-services` as a module:

spring-cloud pom like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>x.y.z</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.yourCompany.spring-cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties/>...
    <dependencies/>...
    <build/>...
    <modules>
        <module>guest-services</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

guest-services pom like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>x.y.z</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.yourCompany.guest</groupId>
    <artifactId>guest-services</artifactId>
    <name>guest-services</name>
    <description>Description for this module</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.yourCompany.spring-cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <properties/>...
    <dependencies/>...
    <build/>...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @tec, unfortunately, the parent project is not a maven project, thus it has no POM. I tried to just create the new project into parent and import parent, but only the child project is being detected and recognized as a maven project, while parent is totally ignored.

Comment: As @tec already said: This is probably not possible. Also, IMHO it is not sensible to try something like this. Either everything is Maven or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have some Java tools as an integral part of a larger project; the tools are extremely unlikely to be used stand-alone.  So the request made sense to me.

The following worked for me:
File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven projects, then select the subdirectory with the POM file.